# Algorithm for obtaining from a set all sequences of size N that include a given subset

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity

To be more specific, the sequences that we want to output can have the elements of the input subset in a different order than the one in the input subset.

**EXAMPLE:** Let's say we have a set {1, 9, 1, 5, 6, 9, 0 , 9, 9, 1, 10} and an input subset {9, 1}.
We want to find all subsets of size 3 that include all elements of the input subset.
This would return the sets {1, 9, 1} , {9, 1, 5}, {9, 9, 1}, {9, 1, 10}.

Of course, the algorithm with the lowest complexity possible is preferred.

**EDIT:** Edited with better terminology. Also, here's what I considered, in pseudocode:

```
1. For each sequence s in the set of size n, do the following: 
    2. Create a list l that is a copy of the input subset i. 
    3. j = 0
    4. For each element e in s, do the following: 
        5. Check if it's in i. 
        If it is, remove that element from l. 
        6. If l is empty, add s to the sequences to return,
        skip to the next sequence (go to step 1)
        7. Increment j. 
        8. if j == n, go to the next sequence (go to step 1)
```

This is what I came up with, but it takes a really awful amount of time
due to the fact that we consider EVERY sequence with no memory of
previously scanned ones whatsoever. I really don't have an idea on how to implement such memory, this is all very new to me.

Comment: The correct terminology here seems to be sequence, not set.

Comment: So what ave **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** ideas / findings / code.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Since, you did not share any of **YOUR** efforts. I will give just some hints and not the complete code. Iterate over every sequence of size 3 and see if the frequency of the elements in the sequence is >= frequency of elements in input subset. This algorithm is O(N) where N is the size of the set.

Comment: Edits have been made accordingly. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: '... it takes a really awful amount of time'. How do you measure the amount of time of seudo code?

Comment: Don't we have to do this basically N*Y times, where Y is sequence size, not  even considering subloop?

Comment: @risingStark can we have memory of previously iterated subsets that way?

Comment: Yes. You are just shifting your window by 1 index. You just need to decrement the frequency of the element that you just kicked out of the window and then increment the frequency of the element that you just captured in the window. This is just a O(1) operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply find all occurrences of that subset and then produce all lists that contain that combination.

In python for example:

```
def get_Allsubsets_withSubset(original_list, N , subset):
    subset_len = len(subset)
    list_len = len(original_list)
    index_of_occurrence = []
    overflow = N - subset_len

    for index in range(len(original_list)-len(subset)):
        if original_list[index: index +len(subset)] == subset:
            index_of_occurrence.append(index)
    final_result = []
    for index in index_of_occurrence:
        for value in range(overflow+1):
            i = index - value
            final_result.append(original_list[i:i+N])
    return final_result
```

Its not beautiful, but I would say its a start